# Nested if statement inside range in template html

Tags: if-statement, go, range

I need a nested `if-statement` inside a `range` in a `golang` `"html/template"`.

Bookmarks.html

```
{{define "bookmarks"}}
<div class="bookmarks">
    {{range .}}
    <div class="bookmark">
        <div class="image">
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="{{.Url}}">
                {if .Img }}
                <img src="/bookmark/get/image?name={{ .Img }}"/>
                {{else}}
                <img src="../static/images/placeholder.jpg"/>
                {{end}}
            </a>
        </div>
    {{end}}
</div>
{{end}}
```

`go run` ends up in:

> panic: template: bookmarks.html:26: unexpected {{end}}

Comment: Change `{if .Img }}` to `{{if .Img }}`.

Comment: wow. Thank you. That was stupid!